# How can I display PHP shell_exec results into a html table?

Tags: php, html, shell-exec

I have a PHP shell_exec command that outputs 5 lines of data for each result, if the `shell_exec` has 1 result it will output 5 lines like so:

```
john
richmond
27
london
dogs
```

The command may have more then 1 result, here is an example of 3 results:

```
    john
    richmond
    27
    london
    dogs
    dave
    archibold
    34
    new york
    cats
    harry
    harris
    33
    dublin
    fish
```

As you can see each result has 5 lines, name, surname, age, city and pet.
I wish to create a html table with the results, however as the number of results could be different each time and they need to be grouped into 5 i am not sure how to acheive this.
This is the desired  HTML output:

```
| Name  | Surname   | Age | City    | Pet        | 
--------------------------------------------------
| john  | richmond  | 27  | london  | dogs cat   |
| dave  | archibold | 34  | newyork | cats cow   |
| harry | harris    | 33  | dublin  | fish horse |
```

From my own research I think I may have to use php `explode` and create an array, I have came up with the following, however not sure how to implement the foreach and what else I require to make it work:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<?php
$str = shell_exec( "shell command" );
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $str); 
$arr = array_chunk($arr,5); 
foreach *

?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Pet</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach(*) { ?>
    <tr class="1">
    <td class="1">
         <i class="cc <?php echo $name;?></i>
    </td>
    <td class="1">
         <i class="cc <?php echo $surname;?></i>
    </td>
    <td class="1">
         <i class="cc <?php echo $age;?></i>
    </td>
    <td class="1">
         <i class="cc <?php echo $city;?></i>
    </td>
    <td class="1">
         <i class="cc <?php echo $pet;?></i>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: PS: as other have pointed in your other question, do yourself a favor, and [indent your code properly](https://blog.programminghub.io/blog/2017/06/07/importance-indentation-programming/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `array_chunk`, you indeed have most of what you need already, you just need to foreach your resulting array, and use a little bit of the [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) magic, to assign your variables.

In short, what `list` is doing, is taking your array elements one by one and assigning them to the variables you would define in your `list` statement.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <?php 
        $array = array_chunk(
            explode(
                PHP_EOL, 
                shell_exec( "shell command" )
            ),
            5
        ); 
    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Pet</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($array as $element) { ?>
                <?php list($name, $surname, $age, $city, $pet) = $element; ?>
                <tr class="1">
                    <td class="1">
                         <i class="cc"><?php echo $name ?></i>
                    </td>
                    <td class="1">
                         <i class="cc"><?php echo $surname ?></i>
                    </td>
                    <td class="1">
                         <i class="cc"><?php echo $age ?></i>
                    </td>
                    <td class="1">
                         <i class="cc"><?php echo $city ?></i>
                    </td>
                    <td class="1">
                         <i class="cc"><?php echo $pet ?></i>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. i have tested the code and i am getting multiple errors : PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/html/orders/test.php on line 24
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /var/www/html/orders/test.php on line 24
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in /var/www/html/orders/test.php on line 24
and the HTML table contains no entries, any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Your table contains no entries because you set the values as classes of your `<i>` elements e.g. `<i class="cc <?php echo $pet ?></i>`. I can edit that in the answer, if you wish. For the undefined offset, most likely you have one or more broken records that makes the list assignation fail. Post us your real data in your question, if you want further troubleshooting

Comment: Actually, having a second look at it, your `i` tag is totally malformed. Fixed that in the answer.